# How to unwrap object into a list when deserializing

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm trying to create json that looks like this

```
"entries" : [
    {
    "name" : <name>,
    "dataPoint" : [
          [long, double],
          [long, double],
        ]
    }
 ]
```

Each data point is a 2-element array of a long and a double

If I have this

```
public class Entry {
   private String name;
   private List<DataPoint> dataPoint;

  <constructor and getters omitted>
}

public class DataPoint{
    List<?> data;

    public DataPoint(long date, double counts) {
        this.data = List.of(date, counts);
    }

    public List<?> getDataPoint() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

I end up with an entry looking like this

```
{
"name" : "20070480",
"data" : [ {
      "dataPoint" : [ 1681792679186, 1096.0 ]
      }, {
      "dataPoint" : [ 1681792680186, 1147.0 ]
      }
}
```

`@JsonUnwrapped` doesn't seem to do anything and I'm not sure that's what I want anyway.  I don't want to unwrap it.  But instead, I want to wrap the fields as a list, instead of being contained in an object

whereas I want it to look like this

```
{
"name" : "20070480",
"dataPoint" : [ 
       [ 1681792679186, 1096.0 ]
       [ 1681792680186, 1147.0 ]
}
```

Is there any way to do this without writing my own serializer?

Comment: You could transform the `List<DataPoint>` into a `List<List<Number>>` before serializing. If that sounds inefficient, you should probably just use a custom serializer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dataPoint: [{ data:`?

Comment: @shmosel Yes, sorry about the typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just annotate `data` (or its getter) with `@JsonValue`:

```
@JsonValue
List<?> data;
```

This tells the serializer to treat `data` as the sole representation of `this` rather than as a property in a JSON object.